# Inputting missing value in primary dataset based on values in secondary dataset and a matching condition

Tags: sas, sas-iml

my understanding of SAS is very elementary. I am trying to do something like this and i need help.

I have a primary dataset A with 20,000 observations where Col1 stores the CITY and Col2 stores the MILES. Col2 contains a lot of missing data. Which is as shown below.

```
+----------------+---------------+
|       Col1     |    Col2       |
+----------------+---------------+
|  Gary,IN       |       242.34  |
+----------------+---------------+
| Lafayette,OH   |       .       |
+----------------+---------------+
|   Ames, IA     |       123.19  |
+----------------+---------------+
|  San Jose,CA   |       212.55  |
+----------------+---------------+
| Schuaumburg,IL |       .       |
+----------------+---------------+
| Santa Cruz,CA  |       454.44  |
+----------------+---------------+
```

I have another secondary dataset B this has around 5000 observations and very similar to dataset A where Col1 stores the CITY and Col2 stores the MILES. However in this dataset B, Col2 DOES NOT CONTAIN MISSING DATA.

```
+----------------+---------------+
|       Col1     |    Col2       |
+----------------+---------------+
| Lafayette,OH   |       321.45  |
+----------------+---------------+
|  San Jose,CA   |       212.55  |
+----------------+---------------+
| Schuaumburg,IL |       176.34  |
+----------------+---------------+
| Santa Cruz,CA  |       454.44  |
+----------------+---------------+
```

My goal is to fill the missing miles in Dataset A based on the miles in Dataset B by matching the city names in col1.

In this example, I am trying to fill in 321.45 in Dataset A from Dataset B and similarly  176.34 by matching Col1 (city names) between the two datasets.

I am need help doing this in SAS

Answer (score 1):

You just have to merge the two datasets. Note that values of Col1 needs to match exactly in the two datasets.

Also, I am assuming that Col1 is unique in dataset B. Otherwise you need to somehow tell more exactly what value you want to use or remove the duplicates (for example by adding nodupkey in proc sort statement).

Here is an example how to merge in SAS:

```
proc sort data=A;
    by Col1;

proc sort data=B;
    by Col1;

data AB;
    merge A(in=a) B(keep=Col1 Col2 rename=(Col2 = Col2_new));
    by Col1;
    if a;
    if missing(Col2) then Col2 = Col2_new;
    drop Col2_new;
run;
```

This includes all observations and columns from dataset A. If Col2 is missing in A then we use the value from B.

Comment: Shouldn't you be dropping col2_new?

Answer (score 1):

Pekka's solution is perfectly working, I add an alternative solution for the sake of completeness.

Sometimes in SAS a `PROC SQL` lets you skip some passages compared to a `DATA` step (with the relative gain in storage resources and computational time), and a `MERGE` is a typical example.

Here you can avoid sorting both input datasets and handling the renaming of variables (here the matching key has the same name `col1` but in general this is not the case).

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select A.col1,
            coalesce(A.col2,B.col2) as col2
        from A left join B
            on A.col1=B.col1
        order by A.col1;
quit;
```

The `coalesce()` function returns the first non missing element encountered in the arguments list.

Comment: I agree. This is nice. Note that you can do `select A.*, ...` if you want to keep everything from A and add only col2 from B.